# IntelliJ Remote Debug does not work at times

Tags: intellij-idea, breakpoints

I am using IntelliJ for development and remote debugging of my OSGI code. Most of the time it works. However, at times I am facing the below issue.
IntelliJ connects and the code stops when running; however, I do not see any values at my breakpoint.
Once I could resolve this problem by removing a swap file. Another possibility is a slow resync between my memory and file values.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my OSGI service and it seems to have resolved the issue. Any details on the internals will be useful.